# Measurement Invariance For Sigle-Item Binary Measures (Between Participants)

Tags: scale-invariance

I have a dataset in which 900 people responded to a single-item binary outcome variable. However, each of the individuals responded to only one of three different binary measurements.

This would result in a dataset like the one below:

```
set.seed(1234)

mydata <- data.frame(id = 1:900, 
                     measure = sample(rep(1:3, each = 300)),
                     response = sample(0:1, size = 900, replace = TRUE))
```

Now, the editor reviewing the paper wants me to provide evidence for the measurement invariance of these three measures. However, I'm confused and unsure whether it is even possible to test measurement invariance for this setup because these are a.) single-item measures and b.) each person responds to only one of the measurements (not all three). So I don't see a way to test for MI.

I could compare the three measures in a logistic regression and see whether responses differ across the three measures, but that wouldn't tell me much about whether they measure the same construct.